# Error while installing gem in Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I created a simple web project in ROR - postgresql as a DB

```
C:\Sites\nested>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Sites\nested>rails -v
Rails 4.0.2
```

When I try to add an automatic foreign key either by command line

```
C:\Sites\nested>gem install automatic_foreign_key
```

or edit the gem file by adding

```
# create automatic foreign key
gem "automatic_foreign_key", "~> 1.3.0"
```

I got the following error when running the server

```
C:\Sites\nested>rails s                                
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:32:in `alias_method': undefined method `to_sql' for class `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Tab leDefinition' (NameError)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:32:in `alias_method_chain'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redhillonrails_core-.2.0/lib/redhillonrails_core/active_record/connection_adapters/table_definition.rb:9:in `block in included'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redhillonrails_core-.2.0/lib/redhillonrails_core/active_record/connection_adapters/table_definition.rb:6:in `class_eval'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redhillonrails_core-.2.0/lib/redhillonrails_core/active_record/connection_adapters/table_definition.rb:6:in `included'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redhillonrails_core-.2.0/lib/redhillonrails_core.rb:32:in `include'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redhillonrails_core-.2.0/lib/redhillonrails_core.rb:32:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/automatic_foreign_key-.3.0/lib/automatic_foreign_key.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/automatic_foreign_key-.3.0/lib/automatic_foreign_key.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in require'
from C:/Sites/nested/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `automatic_foreign_key` was deprecated by its author three years ago. https://github.com/mlomnicki/automatic_foreign_key#schemaplus---new-and-better-automatic_foreign_key You probably shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 1):

FYI this is your error:

```
`alias_method': undefined method `to_sql' for class `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Tab leDefinition' (NameError)
```

Looks like the gem is creating an [`alias_method`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/alias_method) for `.to_sql`. Alias method basicaly calls a method by another name, so you can use it in different contexts

We use `alias_method :name, :title` a lot, because we standardize our validations, meaning we need to keep the same method names each time

---

**Error**

The actual error is caused by your class not having the `to_sql` method. I've never encountered this, so [I looked it up](https://github.com/lomba/schema_plus/issues/106):

Seems the issue is caued by Rails 4. As for a solution, I would suggest that **since [`automatic_foreign_key` hasn't been updated since 2011](http://rubygems.org/gems/automatic_foreign_key), it's going to be incompatible with Rails 4**

If we take that idea as the problem, maybe you could detail how you want it to work & we could create a work-around?

Comment: if its not supported, is downgrading the rails version will solve the problem?

Comment: Sure, but that's not trivial - you can try if you wish, but it would be best to use the latest version

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
C:\Sites\nested>gem install --local automatic_foreign_key
```

and also `bundle install --local` in your project terminal and then edit `gem "automatic_foreign_key", "~> 1.3.0"` in your gem file

Comment: the following error occured

    install --local                      
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Please specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)

Comment: After install in your local system, you may add `bundle install --local` in your project terminal.

Comment: The command didn't execute! the following error 

    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Please specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)

Comment: gem install --local automatic_foreign_key
==> 
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'automatic_foreign_key' (>= 0) in any repository

Comment: mention the gem file version also while installing

Comment: keep the gem file at the exact folder when you are installing. and confirm it, is the correct gem